# Delete a character from an argument passed to a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments, string-manipulation

Suppose in a batch file, say receive.bat, is called with some arguments. Now receive.bat executes and it needs to process these arguments.

Sometimes (but not always), an argument will end  with a trailing slash (e.g. `"C:\a\b\"`). The number of arguments is not fixed and the (only) such argument may appear anywhere in the list of arguments.

How can my .bat file remove the `\` in `\"`, for example, to get `"C:\a\b"`?

---

Update:

I tried the examples below and the 3rd one is not working.
It just said `there should not be a SET here`.

```
SET var=C:\
IF %var:~-1%==\ SET var=%var:~0, -1%
@ECHO %var%

SET var2="C:\\
IF %var2:~-2%==\\ SET var2=%var2:~0, -2%
@ECHO %var2%

SET var3="C:\"
IF %var3:~-2%==\a" SET var3=%var3:~0, -2%
@ECHO %var3%
```

Comment: Have a look at stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952401/remove-trailing-slash-from-batch-file-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting var3 to **"C:\"**, and comparing the last two characters to **\a"**? See below and [this page](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) for help with batch substring extraction.

```
SET var=C:\
IF %var:~-1%==\ SET var=%var:~0,-1%
@ECHO %var%
REM Output: C:

SET var2="C:\
IF %var2:~-1%==\ SET var2=%var2:~0,-1%
@ECHO %var2%
REM Output: "C:

SET var3="C:\"
IF %var3:~-2,1%==\ SET var3=%var3:~0,-2%"
@ECHO %var3%
REM Output: "C:"
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But do you know how can I make this works for a received parameter? For example, I don't want to work with a new variable var, I want to manupulate %1, %2, %3 ...directly. I found %1=%var% or SET %1=%var% doesn't change the value of these parameters.

Comment: You can't change their values, so you have to copy to another variable.